# Run time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the error message that I get:

Run time error '1004'
Cannot run the macro 'Do_Special_Copy'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I have three worksheets with similar fields, I want to consolidate into another worksheet called macro, and below is the code for the macro:

```
Sub Data_Consol()

End Sub

Sub WBLoop()

 Dim wb As Workbook, x As String
 For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> "Macro template" Then
         x = wb.Name
         Workbooks(x).Activate
    End If
    Call Copy_Paste
 Next wb

 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft)).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Range("A1").Activate

Sheets("Template").Select
Sheets("AddFormulae").Visible = True

Sheets("AddFormulae").Select
Range("X2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.Run "Do_Special_Copy"
Sheets("Template").Select
Range("X2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("X:AD").Select
Columns("X:AD").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets("Template").Select
Sheets("AddFormulae").Visible = False

Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub Copy_Paste()
Dim wb As Workbook
 Range("A2").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

' Select

Application.Run "Do_Special_Copy"
Windows("Macro template.xlsm").Activate

' Need to add in code here to find first empty row

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3

End Sub

Sub SelectWorkbook()
'
' SelectWorkbook Macro
'
Windows("ESMS CTSM Q - Call Back.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually we have to ask what of code the error occurs on but that is a moot point here it seems.

Comment: Try to read error message what it said, or atleast please provide us with some code. But main issue will be that you have disabled macros...

Comment: Seems like macro's are turned off.  check this link to know how to turn on macros.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12

Comment: @Sixthsense I enabled and still cannot.

Comment: I don't see a macro called `Do_Special_Copy` in your code. Seems the macro cannot be found. BTW, next time format the code yourself so we can read it.

Comment: If the macro resides in another workbook then you need to qualify it in the string. If it's in the same workbook then you can just call it by typing it's name, no need for the `.Run()` method.

Comment: @MacroMan my macro resides in another workbook, is my code correct then? thx!

Comment: @MacroMan can tell me what is meant by Do_Special_Copy?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error before and unprotecting the sheet did the trick
(Try unprotecting your sheet , if protected , where you are trying to paste data).